# Why am I getting so many br tags

Tags: css, html

I started writing html code and when I view it on chrome, the table is displayed after a long white space. When I inspect the element, on chrome, I get a lot of br tags but I have not given any br tags in the code

How come?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title> Practice </title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="0.00001" align="center" bgcolor="silver">
    <caption align="center"> <big><big><b> Registration Form </b><big><big> </caption><br><br>
<form name="My Form" action="" method="">
<tr>
<td> Username </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="t1" size="6"/> </td>
</tr><br><br>

<tr>
<td> Password </td>
<td> <input type="password" name="t2" size="6"/> </td>
</tr><br><br>

<tr>
<td> Name </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="t3" size="30"/> </td>
</tr><br><br>

<tr>
<td> Address </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="t4" size="30"/> </td>
</tr><br><br>

<tr>
<td> Country </td>
<td><select name="s1">
<option> Select Your Country </option>
<option> Afghanistan </option>
<option> Bangladesh </option>
<option> China </option>
<option> India </option>
<option> Russia </option>
</select></td>
</tr><br><br>

<tr>
<td> Zip Code </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="t5" size="6"/> </td>
</tr><br><br>

<tr>
<td> Email </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="t6" size="30"/> </td>
</tr><br><br>

<tr>
<td>Sex</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="r1" value="100" checked/>Male
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="102"/>Female</td>
</tr><br><br>

<tr>
<td>Language</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="r1" value="100" checked/>English
<input type="checkbox" name="r2" value="102"/>Non English</td>
</tr><br><br>

<tr>
<td> About </td>
<td><textarea name="a1" rows="5" cols="32"> </textarea></td>
</tr><br><br>

<tr align="centre">
<td><input type="submit" name="b2" value="submit here"/></td>
</tr><br><br>

</form>
</table>
```

Comment: **a lot of br tags but i have not given any br tags in the code please help** read your code again bud

Comment: Because `<br />` elements are invalid child elements for a `<table>`, browsers typically remove them from the `<table>` and insert them beforehand. Do not put any element other than `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>` or `<tr>` directly within a `<table>`. And if *you* didn't put those `<br />` elements in there you need to have a chat with whoever else has access to your server/computer.

Comment: You could start by running your original code through the w3 validator

Comment: @Dummy - Perhaps we can assume the posted code is what chrome showed?

Comment: The main issue was lose LineFeeds - see my answer for more issues solved

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is `<br>`. Use `Inspect Element` to check what's causing so much gap before table. There might be some kind of `margin` before table.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of unnecessary "br" tags in your code, inside your table. Remove them all and all will be fine! Cheers.

Comment: I think that is what he is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, This might solve your issues

```
  <table border="0.00001" align="center" bgcolor="silver" cellpadding="10">
    <caption align="center"><b> Registration Form </b> </caption><br><br>
<form name="My Form" action="" method="">
<tr>
<td> Username </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="t1" size="6"/> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Password </td>
<td> <input type="password" name="t2" size="6"/> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Name </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="t3" size="30"/> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Address </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="t4" size="30"/> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Country </td>
<td><select name="s1">
<option> Select Your Country </option>
<option> Afghanistan </option>
<option> Bangladesh </option>
<option> China </option>
<option> India </option>
<option> Russia </option>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Zip Code </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="t5" size="6"/> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Email </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="t6" size="30"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sex</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="r1" value="100" checked/>Male
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="102"/>Female</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Language</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="r1" value="100" checked/>English
<input type="checkbox" name="r2" value="102"/>Non English</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> About </td>
<td><textarea name="a1" rows="5" cols="32"> </textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr align="centre">
<td><input type="submit" name="b2" value="submit here"/></td>
</tr>

</form>
</table>
```

Just removed some un-necessary tags, that might be causing issues. Please try

Comment: This is not valid HTML

Answer (score 0):

You had [a lot of LF](https://superuser.com/questions/545461/replace-carriage-return-and-line-feed-in-notepad) in your page. You need to check your editor

Also you had invalid tags and missed CSS

Here is a fixed version that validates

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Practice </title>
  <style>
    table {
      border: 0.00001px;
      background-color: silver;
      margin: 0px auto;
    }
    
    caption {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: x-large;
    }
    
    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="MyForm">
    <table>
      <caption>Registration Form</caption>
      <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="t1" size="6" /> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="t2" size="6" /> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="t3" size="30" /> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="t4" size="30" /> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>
          <select name="s1">
            <option> Select Your Country </option>
            <option> Afghanistan </option>
            <option> Bangladesh </option>
            <option> China </option>
            <option> India </option>
            <option> Russia </option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zip Code</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="t5" size="6" /> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="t6" size="30" /> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="r1" value="100" checked/>Male
          <input type="radio" name="r1" value="102" />Female</td>
          <input type="radio" name="r1" value="103" />Irrelevant</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Language</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="r1" value="100" checked/>English
          <input type="checkbox" name="r2" value="102" />Non English</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>About</td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="a1" rows="5" cols="32"> </textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="center" colspan="2">
          <input type="submit" name="b2" value="submit here" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```